# MailMessage sends mail with empty subject and attachments

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I'm trying to send an email through my relay smtp with an html body, subject and optional attachments. The sending works without exceptions however, the mail which is being sent ends up with an empty subject and no attachments which should get files from the wwwroot folder of my web application which is being hosted on the same domain as my API and console app. This console app will be called from the task scheduler. This program has my API as dependency so that it can call the `ProcessQueue` task. this one is being called correctly from my console application. To get data for the email the code will retreive data from the MailQueue table and then fill the mailmessage like so:

```
    public async Task ProcessQueue(int range, bool send)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "outbound.domain",
            Port = 587,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@domain.com", "")
        };

        var items = await _context.MailQueues.Take(range).ToListAsync();

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            try
            {
                message.From = new MailAddress(item.From);
                message.Subject = item.Subject; // The subject is being filled correctly in my situation, but when the email arrives it isn't
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.To.Add(item.To);
                message.Body = item.Content;
                if (send)
                {
                    AddAttachments(message, item.Docs);
                    client.Send(message);
                    _context.MailQueues.Remove(item);
                    message.To.Clear();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                item.Exception = ex.ToString();
                _context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
```

The attachment method:

```
    private void AddAttachments(MailMessage message, string docs)
    {
        if (docs != null)
        {
            List<string> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(docs);
            foreach (string item2 in list)
            {
                Attachment item = new Attachment(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/wwwroot/documents/") + item2)
                {
                    Name = item2
                };
                message.Attachments.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

The structure of my domain:

**domain.com > webapplicatie (contains my web app and its wwwroot folder)**

**domain.com > webapi (contains my web api)**

**domain.com > mailqueuer (the location of my console application)**

My goal is to send the message with optional attachments, which are located in the web app's wwwroot folder, and its subject. All the data of the MailQueue objects are filled! but still I get this problem.

Does somebody know a solution to this?

Comment: How about _not_ catching and swallowing exceptions and see what exception occurs?

Comment: I can try, but if there's an exception it should show it in the database, I am going to try your suggestion now

Comment: As I said, there's no exception

Comment: Start by putting `MailMessage message = new MailMessage();` in the loop instead of outside. Maybe it helps.

Comment: I did and still the same. Is it possible that it's related to the From adress and/or spam folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by putting the database and smtp logic for the MailQueue into the console application. I don't exactly know why my question isn't working but I'm open for answers and suggestions!